# leaflet context menu + marker dragging

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-editable

I need to start dragging generated markers from context menu, now i got this:

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
        maxClusterRadius: 50
    });
    var datalen = data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < datalen; i++) {

        var znakIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: data[i]['src'],
            iconSize: [35, 35]
        });
        var id = data[i]['id'];
        var marker = new L.marker(data[i]['coords'], {
            icon: znakIcon,
            myCustomId: id,
            contextmenu: true,
            contextmenuItems: [{
                    separator: true,
                    index: 0
                },
                {
                    text: 'edit',
                    index: 0,
                    callback: markeredit
                },

                {
                    separator: true,
                    index: 0
                }
            ]
        }, ).on('dblclick', markerOnClick);
```

But "markeredit" doesnt know what marker needed to drag. I can do it on "click" event on marker with simple code:

```
this.enableEdit();
```

How could i realize that with context menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

callback:

```
callback: markerOnClick
```

Code:

```
function markerOnClick(e) {
        e.relatedTarget.enableEdit();
    }
```

Works perfectly ;)